# Does voltage depends on the charge present in an element?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-circuits, electric-fields, charge, voltage

Does the voltage depend on the charge present in a battery ?
I know in capacitors q=cv. Hence charge present is proportional to voltage.
Is it the same in the case of batteries?

Comment: What are your thoughts on it?

Comment: it doesn't depend on charge